# Regarding NodeJs and big data

Tags: mysql, node.js, bigdata

Currently, I'm developing one project and there are lots of MySQL query operations with billions of records and also mathematic operation included and it takes more time to perform the query.

so I need your help in choosing technology for big data and DB operation

Currently, I'm using nodejs and MySQL DB

Thanks for giving me the right way to develop this.

Comment: That depends on the nature of your data. e.g. if you are having meta data regarding entities or you have unstructured data, but all in all you can improve backend storage of your data at this point.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your data. If your data is homogeneous (most of the rows has the same number of columns) and you need to perform complex queries with tons of joins, using a relational database as MySQL is a good option. You can also try other relational databases like Oracle DB, MariaDB and others. It shouldn't be difficult to export your current database and try if the performance improves.

On the other way, if your data is heterogenous and you don't need to perform complex join queries, a NoSQL database can be your option. There are a lot of them but one of the most famous ones is MongoDB. Moreover, Mongo has very good integration with NodeJS. Your main problem would be to convert your actual relational database to a non-relational database.

Comment: Hello @pabol rp thanks for answer. can we use spark SQL? it is good to perform for fast result ?